# Как в php записывать json обьекты?

Tags: php, json

У меня есть обьект:

```
 const cont= {
  "project_id": 14497,
  "status_id": 125849,
"name":"сделка",
  "responsible_id": 44438,
"fields": [
{
"id": 403726,
"value": "ТЕСТОВОЕ ИМЯ"
},
{
"id": 403727,
"value":  "89503186599"
},
{
"id": 403729,
"value": "Здесь будет комментарий"
}
]
}
```

Как его можно преобразовать для php, чтобы отправить curl запрос. Я записал следующим образом, но этот вариант выдает ошибку.

```
$data = array(
 
    "project_id"=> 14497,
    "status_id"=> 125849,
    "name"=> "string",
    "responsible_id"=>44438,
    "budget"=>123,
    "currency_id"=> 1,
    "fields"=>array(
        
        "id"=>403726,
        "value"=>"ТЕСТОВОЕ ИМЯ",
        
        "id"=> 403727,
        "value"=> "89503186599",
        
        "id"=>403729,
        "value"=>"Здесь будет комментарий"
        
    )
);
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Как минимум в `fields` такой структуры быть не может, должно быть что-то вроде `"fields" => [["id" => 403726, "value" => "ТЕСТОВОЕ ИМЯ" ], ["id" => 403727, "value" => "89503186599"], ["id" => 403729, "value" => "Здесь будет комментарий" ]]`. В одном массиве не может быть одновременно несколько одинаковых ключей.

Comment: `$arr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);`